# Can Von Neumann bit extraction be made more efficient?

Tags: randomness, entropy

I want to develop a previous [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9469/unbiasing-of-sequences) regarding Von Neumann debiasing /randomness extraction.

The typical solution (as posted) is to take pairs of throws and output a bit based on a comparison of the two throws.  This is the most simple solution.

My problem is that it's very wasteful of input entropy.  The biased die can have values 1 - 6, but only a single bit is output.  So 2 x log2(6) bits in, produce 1 bit out.  It's actually less as the throws may be discarded if identical.  What happens if the die is a D & D D120 (Disdyakis triacontahedron - 120 sides)?  You'd be inputting 13.8 bits of entropy, and getting (practically) less than 1.  That's incredibly wasteful of precious entropy.  Is there a clever variant of Von Neumann that can output more than a single bit at a time?

My particular interest is actually not a bigger die, but more of them.  For example you simultaneously throw 6 biased regular dice.  Can you get better than 1 purely random bit out per pair of throwing rounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are going to throw a 6-sided die N times.  You can convert that to an integer in the range $[0,6^N-1]$, by viewing the sequence of N outcomes as a base-6 representation of an integer.  This gives you a random number chosenly uniformly at random from $[0,6^N-1]$.

Now pick a value of $k$ such that $2^k < 6^N$.  Let $Y = \lfloor 6^N/2^k \rfloor \times 2^k$.  You can now use the following algorithm to output a $k$-bit number (much of the time):

Generate a random number from the range $[0,6^N-1]$ by tossing a 6-sided die $N$ times.  Suppose the number you get is $x$.  If $x < Y$, then output the value $x \bmod 2^k$ (which can be viewed as $k$ bits).  Otherwise, output nothing -- you will have to re-roll.

This produces a uniform random distribution on $k$-bit values.  It produces output on any given attempt with probability $Y/6^N$; on average, the expected number of times you'll have to repeat this procedure is $6^N/Y$, which is a bit more than $1$ (but not much more than $1$, as long as you're not too greedy and don't pick $k$ too large).

It's possible to do a bit better, by saving information about the value of $x-Y$ when you repeat the process, but this might not make a big difference in practice.

See also [Generating uniformly distributed random numbers using a coin](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/570/755) and [Is rejection sampling the only way to get a truly uniform distribution of random numbers?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2605/755) and [How to simulate a die given a fair coin](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29204/755) and [Isn't std::bernoulli_distribution inefficient? Designing a bit-parallel Bernoulli generator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14525/755).

Comment: I can handle the multiplications, but what are the brackets in ⌊6N/2k⌋ ?  Is that integer floor of?

Comment: @PaulUszak, yes.